# Error while using Git on windows 7

Tags: git, windows-7, installation

I have downloaded and installed the Git setup on Windows 7. But whenever I try to create/clone or init a new repo, it generates the following error.

> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Can anyone please suggest me that what possibly is it asking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With msysgit, you need to launch a special shell, through [`<path/to/msysgit>/git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/devel/git-cmd.bat).
That will take care of the `PATH` for you.

And of you need git for interacting with GitHub repositories, don't forget [**windows.github.com**](http://windows.github.com/).
It also include an msysgit distribution and set the `PATH` correctly as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the folder which [contains the git executable to your Windows Path](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: I just tried what you suggested but it still doesn't work. Earlier when I installed git on Windows XP, it was automatically added to the path but now on Windows 7, i don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the bash provided with MSysGit, you shouldn't have this problem.